# How do I get to record my ppg signal and save the data in csv file in my phone?

Tags: flutter, dart, export-to-csv, record

I am a beginner to flutter software and I am using dart language. I can't seem to find any tips that helps me to record ppg signal with a timer and then saving the data in csv file in my vivo phone. I need to save in the csv file so that i can convert it in matlab to analyse it. Whoever knows solution for this, please do answer me... I need to complete my project by today...

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using this tutorial to learn how it works.

https://betterprogramming.pub/measuring-your-heart-rate-using-your-phones-camera-and-flutter-f444d3c4272a

Then you can use a package like [csv](https://pub.dev/packages/csv) and convert rows to csv format. Then save it in a file

```
String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
```

```
String dir = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

String file = "$dir";

File ppgSignals = File(file + "/fileName.csv");

ppgSignals.writeAsString(csv)
```

Comment: Hii, thank you for replying!! I have used the link to build my app but after that, i don't know how to save my data once i start measuring. Is there any coding that can help me to measure the signals for 30s and then record the 30s data in my phone..??

Comment: Once you start measuring you will havea listener event which will keep listening to data. Add it to a list and when the user status measuring. Convert this list to an array as shown in the csv package and add it to a row ina csv and export